# locale specific download links

Tags: html, jsp, tomcat

i'm trying to provide download links of browsers in my application which is available in many european languages.

How can I direct a user to their own countries download page.

For eg: for firefox, if an italian logs in he should be directed to the italian page. Same for all browsers.

I use tomcat 6 as the application server

Comment: Hm, with Apache you can use [content negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html), but I don't know about Tomcat.

Comment: Most browser manufactures have an own (automatic) language selection on their website, so if you link to the international homepage, the users browser language will be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

I'd parse the [Accept-Language header](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-accept-lang-locales) … but only use it to decide which version the big link at the top of the page should link to, a table of alternative versions below, or a link to other versions avoids problems with making wrong assumptions about a user's preferences.

For example:

[image: The Firefox download page consists of]

- A big link that tells you what you will get (including platform and language)
- A link to a page showing all the other versions which links to

[image: a table showing all the languages and platforms]